# Ctrl + Alt + 5 behavior changed in 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, unity, shortcut-keys

I'm using stock Ubuntu with Unity installed, and this problem is totally annoying.

In 12.04, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> (Toggle Maximization State) would maximize/restore a window's state. E.g.:

1. Open a terminal (which covers ~25% of the screen)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> and it's maximized
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> again, and it's back to covering 25% of the screen.

In 14.04, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> the first time will maximize a window, but on the second time it will start toggling between maximized and full-screen (w/o menus). It won't ever restore the window's size to the non-maximized state.

I know there's another key that can do it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd> = Restore Window), however, pressing this one twice will minimize the window entirely.

Is there a way to restore the behavior from 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

Well, after installing Metacity (`sudo apt-get install gnome-session-fallback`), the behavior is as expected. From that I gather that the altered behavior is local to the Unity Launcher.

Don't think I can do much about it. But since I'm running inside a VirtualBox VM on a Win 8.1 system, and since Ubuntu 14.04 is way wayyy slower than 12.04 (especially with Unity Launcher), I think I'll stick with Metacity, which is a 2D display manager (as opposed to Unity Launcher or Gnome Compize, which are 3D and are killing the whole VM experience for me).

Answer (score 0):

Try the Unity Tweak tool; research if you think this add on addresses functionality. I also did something to change desktop appearance. Type desktop settings in search bar and customize to see if that can help.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything relevant in unity-tweak-tool.